# BigInteger to string

Tags: java, arrays, tostring, biginteger

I have a very big integer number (about 200000 digits). I need to print this value on Console.

```
System.out.println(myBigInt);
```

This action(print to console and implicit converting from `Biginteger` to `String`) takes a long time. I have a idea. Convert BigInteger to byteArray and then this byteArray convert to string. Following code converting byte array to `String`:

```
public static String bytesToStringUTFCustom(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] buffer = new char[bytes.length >> 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
            int bpos = i << 1;
            char c = (char)(((bytes[bpos]&0x00FF)<<8) + (bytes[bpos+1]&0x00FF));
            buffer[i] = c;
        }
        return new String(buffer);
    }
```

The problem is method of `BigInteger toByteArray()` returns a byte array containing the two's-complement representation of this `BigInteger`. How i can coverting `bytearray` in this representation to string?

Comment: I somehow doubt that the converting takes that much time. The printing on the console will probably take most of the needed time..

Comment: Consoles are used for user interaction. I very much doubt that a user 'can' interact with a 200k digit number. Why are you doing this? Perhaps we can provide an alternative solution that would be of more help to you?

Comment: The obvious thing to do is to separate out the "conversion to string" part from the "writing to console" part. Time each separately.

Comment: This is NOT going to work.  Your byte array isn't going to be in base-10, so converting pairs of bytes into characters isn't going to give you the decimal representation.

Answer (score 0):

To print it, just use:

```
System.out.println(myBigInt.toString());
```

or

```
System.out.println(myBigInt);
```

The conversion itself takes very little time; printing your number to the console is what takes time. Also, converting to a byte array and then to a string will, if anything, take longer.